# How to do JSLint in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim, lint

I spend my days in vim, currently writing a lot of JavaScript. I've been trying to find a way to integrate JSLint or something similar into vim to improve my coding. Has anyone managed to do something like this?

I tried this: [Javascript Syntax Checking From Vim](http://mikecantelon.com/story/javascript-syntax-checking-vim), unfortunately the output is very crude.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can follow the intructions from [JSLint web-service + VIM integration](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/IDE) or do what I did:

Download http://jslint.webvm.net/mylintrun.js and http://www.jslint.com/fulljslint.js
 and put them in a directory of your choice.

Then add the following line to the beginning of mylintrun.js:

```
var filename= arguments[0];
```

and change last line of code in mylintrun.js ("print( ...)") to:

```
 print ( filename + ":" + (obj["line"] + 1) + ":" + (obj["character"] + 1) + ":" + obj["reason"] );
```

This makes in mylintrun.js output a error list that can be used with the VIM quickfix window (:copen).

Now set the following in VIM:

```
set makeprg=cat\ %\ \\\|\ /my/path/to/js\ /my/path/to/mylintrun.js\ %
set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

where you have to change */my/path/to/js* to the path to SpiderMonkey and */my/path/to/mylintrun.js* to the path where you put the JS files.

Now, you can use **:make** in VIM and use the *quickfix* window (:he quickfix-window) to jump from error to error.

Comment: Why are you catting the buffer and passing it as an argument to mylintrun?

Comment: @jamessan: the mylintrun.js script reads the file from stdin. So that's what the catting is for. For the error output mylintrun.js needs also the file name, so it is given as an argument. You could modify the script to open the file for reading instead of reading from stdin (making the cat unnecessary). But I didn't want to bother with this... and I believe there is a problem reading files if you have a JavaScript engine compiled w/o the FileObject

Comment: what is 'the path to SpiderMonkey' on your machine - I've got a few on mine

Comment: I can't get at mylintrun.js, is there an alternative location. it appears to be dead

Comment: @dsjbirch: try this https://github.com/anatoliychakkaev/.vim/blob/master/mylintrun.js

Comment: I've opted for another approach using node I'll outline in a response

Comment: Now there is `jslint.vim` available at [github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim/). Even though it's in alpha, it's pretty stable for me.

Comment: The links to mylintrun.js and fulljslint.js are broken which is rendering this answer less than useful because it relies heavily on them. Please can you update with working urls? Otherwise I'll need to delete this answer which is a bummer because it looks quite good and has helped a lot of folks. Thanks.

Answer (score 188):

The best-practice way IMO is:

1. Install [Syntastic Vim plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) - Best syntax-checker around for plenty of languages, plus it integrates with Vim's *location-list* (==*quickfix*) window.

- I recommend [cloning from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) and installing using a plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) or [Pathogen](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332), since it's more frequently updated.

2. Choose one of the two options below:

### JSLint

1. Install `jsl` (JSLint executable) using your favorite package manager (Ubuntu's `apt-get`, Mac's [home `brew`](https://brew.sh/), etc.).

### Community-driven [jshint.com](https://jshint.com/) (better than JSLint)

1. Install *node.js* using your favorite package manager.
2. Install *Node Package Manager*: 'curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh' **EDIT: npm IS PART OF node.js NOW**

   - See [http://npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/) for more info.
3. Install *jshint* globally: 'npm install jshint -g'
4. Put your jshint *config* file in your *$HOME* dir: '~/.jshintrc'

   - [Here's JSHint-Node's example configuration file](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc), they pulled from mine and added more stuff.
   - [Here's my original copy, which you can also start from](https://github.com/oryband/dotfiles/blob/master/jshintrc).
5. Overwrite *Syntastic*'s `syntax_checkers/javascript.vim` file with [this one](https://github.com/factorylabs/vimfiles/blob/master/home/.vim/syntax_checkers/javascript.vim) - **EDIT: NO LONGER NECESSARY WITH NEWEST SYNTASTIC VERSION.**

   - Script [copied](https://github.com/factorylabs/vimfiles/blob/master/home/.vim/syntax_checkers/javascript.vim) from [FactorayLab's really helpful Vim GitHub page](https://github.com/factorylabs/vimfiles/), which I recommend every Vim user to check out.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: I'm giving this a try right now. Tried cloning Syntastic and using the "rake install" command and then replaced the javascrip.vim file with yours. Still can't figure out how to use it, :SyntasticEnable doesn't do anything as far as I can see. I'll keep trying though..

Comment: Ok, noticed that Syntastic requires ballon_eval, wich isn't supported in MacVim. Too bad..

Comment: @Claes Mogren: I guess somebody should get involved in the [Syntatic GitHub repo](https://github.com/sjl/syntastic) and add automatic `jshint` detection, in order to skip the step where you have to overwrite Syntastic's `javascript.vim` with our own custom one.

Comment: I agree, might give it a try myself. :-)

Comment: Tried adding it, hope it (or a prettier version of it) gets pulled  https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/pull/47

Comment: @Claes Mogren: Wow, that was quick. Way to go man! :) Now this tool is even more helpful.

Comment: My patch was pulled by scrooloose yesterday so you might want to update the answer. (And please try that it works :-))

Comment: Just found this; I've followed the instructions, and can verify that Syntastic is installed, but nothing happens on my .js files... Can someone explain how to enable it?

Comment: @MattFeifarek - You're welcome to consult my .vimrc file for help. There're more than one cause for this to not work on your machine: https://github.com/oryband/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: do you have any advice on debugging this configuration. I've installed all these things, but I'm not sure what is wrong or how to use.

Comment: I just spent a long time trying to figure out why nothing appeared to be happening... if you pulled Ory's .jshintrc be aware that there's a trailing comma after "google" in the "predef" object that causes jshint to fail to load and Syntastic to fail silently.

Comment: @ThePants Heh, guess I should update it. :) Thanks for the notice. Guess we can never evade typos.

Comment: @ThePants Just edited the answer and added the developer's repository updated configuration example. They pulled from me originally, but have kept updating it since then. Enjoy!

Comment: jsl for Windows: http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm also, watch out in the jsl.vim file for this issue: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/shellescape-doesn-t-work-in-Windows-with-shellslash-set-td1211618.html

Comment: Already had syntastic and node/npm installed, and this worked perfectly first try. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Syntasic is no longer supported :(

Answer (score 17):

Another option is [jslint.vim](http://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim) from Jesse Hallet. It's available on GitHub and works with or without Vim's QuickFix window. It's a nice plugin!

Comment: +1 for this. Works great. Conveniently downloadable from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2729. Note, on Windows you'll need to install Ruby.

Comment: Also be sure to check out JSHint, mentioned below.

Comment: Project is no longer under development.

Answer (score 6):

I've been very happy using node-lint

```
sudo npm -g install jslint
```

Then whack this somewhere in your `.vim`

```
set makeprg=jslint\ %
set errorformat=%-P%f,
        \%E%>\ #%n\ %m,%Z%.%#Line\ %l\\,\ Pos\ %c,
        \%-G%f\ is\ OK.,%-Q
```

Now a `:make` will run jslint. Errors appear in the quickfix window.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the Mac OS instructions updated for Nov. 2012. Assumes you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed in order to get Node.js, and that you've already installed Syntastic for Vim (I use https://github.com/carlhuda/janus which provides this automatically):

```
$ brew install node.js
$ npm install -g jshint
```

Then add '/usr/local/share/npm/bin' to your PATH (probably in ~/.bashrc). For example, add the line:
`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin"`

restart your Terminal and check that

`$ jshint`

is executable from the command line. Syntastic will discover jsHint automatically. Restart MacVim and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Much better is to pipe the results through Lynx to deal with JSLint's unfortunate choice of HTML for output format. I have a blog post on how to do it here:

http://www.fleegix.org/articles/2008-09-06-jslint-in-vim-through-lynx