# How do you use vim's quickfix feature?

Tags: vim, jslint

I'm a pretty new Vim user and I've found that its learning curve is quite steep (at least for me). I just installed [this vim script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/628872#628872) for JavaScriptLint error checking, which shows errors in vim's quickfix window once I save a buffer.

However, I don't know what to do next.. How do I 'scroll' through all the errors? How do I close the quickfix 'window'? How do I get it to check for errors after I've made changes to my code?

I've looked at the vim quickfix docs but the amount of commands are overwhelming and I can't seem to find what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

A side question: is there any way to have javascriptlint check for js errors for code residing in a .html file?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

There are a lot of [commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window) for quickfix as you have said, but I tend to find I only use a small subset of them:

```
:copen " Open the quickfix window
:ccl   " Close it
:cw    " Open it if there are "errors", close it otherwise (some people prefer this)
:cn    " Go to the next error in the window
:cp    " Go to the previous error in the window
:cnf   " Go to the first error in the next file
:.cc   " Go to error under cursor (if cursor is in quickfix window)
```

I tend to use this with `:make` and `:vimgrep`, so I can't comment on the Javascript lint checker, but this should give you something to get started.

Regarding the general use of JavascriptLint, I'm not a javascript programmer, but it looks like the script exposes a function called "JavascriptLint", so if you want to call it manually, you can use `:call JavascriptLint()`.  However, it works on the disk copy of the file, so it'll have to be saved first.  If (and only if) the command line `jsl` works on html files, you should be able to use `:call JavascriptLint()` on an html file to check the internal javascript.  You could also do:

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.html call JavascriptLint()
```

to automate it.  If `jsl` doesn't support html files, then (short of patching the application or asking the author to change it), it's probably a lost cause...

Comment: Thanks, those commands are a good start, I'll just have to play around a bit and get used to how it works.

If I use :cn to go to an error in the qf window, can I jump to the window with my code without exiting the qf window? Can it jump to the line that has an error?

And your suggestion of using :call works, however it follows <script src> links which isn't what I want.

Comment: @hora: `:cn` shouldn't close the qf window, but it will switch to the window containing the error: is this what you mean by "jump"?  You can quickly switch back with `Ctrl-W p` or `:wincmd p`, so you could do `:command! CN :cn | wincmd p<CR>` or something like that (untested).  This should give you a `:CN` command that goes to the next error without switching out of the quickfix window.  Alternatively you could do something like `:au BufWinEnter quickfix nmap <buffer> <Enter> :.cc | wincmd p<CR>` (again untested) and use Enter to select an error without switching out of the quickfix window.

Comment: For a beginner "You could also do: 'somecodehere' to automate it" does not mean much. It means that the shown line of code must be placed in ~/.vimrc (_VIMRC on windows AFAIK) and from the next start of VIM every time the file is saved this command will be invoked. Right?

Comment: how to remove one entry from the `:chi` btw?

Answer (score 75):

The easiest way to navigate the quickfix list (or the location list, for that matter) is [the `unimpaired` plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired).

Once the quickfix window is populated, `]q` and `[q` go forward and back (respectively) in the quickfix list.  `[Q` and `]Q` go to the beginning and end (which is especially handy if you only have one item in the list; this makes vim complain about `]q` and `[q`).  So the workflow is:

1. Run whatever command populates the quickfix list
2. Type `[Q` to go to the first item
3. Scroll through subsequent items (if any) with `]q` and `[q`

If you're using Syntastic, you'll get the location list instead of the quickfix list.  No problem; just use `[L`, `]L`, `[l`, and `]l` in the same way.

`unimpaired` has loads of other handy mappings too -- `[e` and `]e` "bubble" lines up and down, `[<Space>` and `]<Space>` insert blank lines above and below, etc.  I was surprised nobody mentioned it here before; that's probably because it didn't exist until January 2010, though the question was asked in 2009.

Answer (score 34):

Put the following two lines in your .vimrc file:

```
map <C-j> :cn<CR>
map <C-k> :cp<CR>
```

Now you can navigate through the errors using ctrl-j and ctrl-k, which mimics the standard down and up motion commands j and k.

Comment: `<c-j>` sometime (depends on the terminal?!) is erroneous or altogether not working, because it means the same as <NL>  // the easiest ist, to to use `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` instead // otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304421/trouble-mapping-c-j-in-vim-with-latex-suite

Comment: I decided to use F8 and F9, like this: `noremap <F7> :cprevious<CR>` and `noremap <F8> :cnext<CR>` in `.vimrc`

Comment: I already use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` to navigate between vim splits and tmux panes with [vim tmux navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator). The combinations `<C-M-j>` and `<C-M-k>` might be an alternative.

Comment: `<M-n>` and `<M-N>` feel right to me since they match the `/` search jumping, whereas `j` and `k` usually deal with one line at a time.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use `:cc 2` (or any other number) to jump to, in this case, the second error in the quickfix window.  Navigating with `:cn`, `:cc 4`, etc will put the cursor on the line in question.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to @DrAl's great answer about how to open and close the quick window and navigate between entries, I made an image to show some of the other quick fix navigation commands.

Each group of 3 files below represents a set of quickfix results, e.g. from a vimgrep. cnewer and colder are for going through historic result sets.
[image]

Comment: Very handy intuitive reference, I will keep this as a desktop wallpaper perhaps

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about older/newer! Is there anyway to browse the older lists without blindly stepping backwards? And for example see how many old quickfix lists there are?

Comment: @Moberg I NEED TO KNOW THIS TOO. Could you help?

Comment: @Moberg ,VimNing and anyone else finding this in the future. You're probably looking for :chi[story]

Comment: Great explanation with picture, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this option didn't exist when this question was written (or maybe I'm embarrassing myself because there's something in my `.vimrc` that makes this happen) but when I get a `Quickfix List`, I just navigate it with `j` and `k` then hit `<CR>` (i.e. the Enter key) to jump to that place in the file.

Then, to get back to the `Quickfix List` I type `Ctrl`+`W` `j` for "move down a window" and I'm back.

Finally, when I'm done, I just type `:q`, like I would to close any normal window.

Comment: That's what I would like to do, but I get "Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off".

Comment: You probably have over-ridden your Enter key. I had for example `nmap <CR> o<Esc>`, so I could add new-lines in normal mode.

Answer (score 8):

The best-practice way of integrating JavaScript syntax-checking is using the [*Syntastic* Vim plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447), which is using Vim's *location-list* (which is parallel to the *quickfix*) window.

I've written answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600) explaining how to do it, plus also how to get **source-code browsing / tag-list** for Vim using the community-driven [jshint.com](http://jshint.com) (which is way better than JSLint IMO) and Mozilla's *[DoctorJS](http://DoctorJS)* (formerly *jsctags*).

Answer (score 6):

the quickfix window is operated mostly like any other vim window: j down a line, k up a line, :cn to jump to the next error/warning, etc.

experiment!

Comment: +1 for experimentation, that's pretty much how I learned everything.

Answer (score 0):

Although this requires > Vim 7.4.858, the cdo (or ldo for location lists) command allows updating a non-contiguous set of lines in a way you could once only do with sed:

```
:vimgrep /re/ %:p
:cdo! norm @a
# or
:cdo! s/re/repl/
```

The above shows running a recorded macro or a simple search and replace. Missing seems to a be a way to pipe through and external command as you can with  `:range! command`