# Trouble mapping <C-j> in Vim with latex-suite

Tags: vim, latex, mapping

I wanted to map `<C-j>` to switch to the next window below the current one

```
map <C-j> <C-w>j
```

However, it goes into Insert mode instead of moving the window below. Why?

## Solution attempted:

I have `latex-suite` installed. So I tried to query what `<C-j>` is mapped to

```
:map <C-j>
```

And I get the following output:

```
v  <NL>          <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
n  <NL>          <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
o  <NL>          <C-W>j
```

This means that I should change the mapping of `<Plug>IMAP_JumpForward`. I read around a bit and I found out it's related to the `<++>` placeholders that you can jump to using `<C-j>` during Insert mode. So, based on my reading, I learned I could change the mapping using the following line in `.vimrc`:

```
imap <C-space> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

But no, it doesn't work as `<C-j>` used to. I'll try to illustrate. I type the following (the `_` represents the cursor):

```
\documentclass{}_
```

Then I get

```
\documentclass{_}<++>
```

Then I try to type in some text

```
\documentclass{article_}<++>
```

So now I press `<C-space>`. This is what happens: it goes out of Insert mode and I'll be in the following situation:

```
\documentclass{articl_e}<++>
```

## Problem summary:

1. After `map <C-j> <C-w>j`, `<C-j>` goes into Insert mode.
2. After `imap <C-space> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward`, `<C-space>` doesn't jump to the next `<++>` placeholder. It goes out of Insert mode and cursor backs up one character.

What's the matter? Anything I missed?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest two things:

1. firstly, target the mappings:

   ```
   nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
   ```
2. secondly, find out what mappings interfere (and where they come from) by doing

   ```
   verbose nmap <C-j>     
   verbose nmap <C-w>
   verbose nmap j
   ```

see also `:map`, `:imap`, `:vmap`, `:noremap` etc.

Comment: `verbose map <C-j>` says it was last set from `~/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim`. Right. I thought `.vimrc` is the last script to be sourced? Why is `imaps.vim` overriding my `nnoremap`s in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem; for me, it was behaving weirdly since the `<C-j>` from vim-latex is mapped for the normal visual and insert modes. I kind of felt that after seeing this answer and checking the 'imaps.vim' file in the '\bundle\vim-latex\plugin' directory. I put the following code in my vimrc and it seems to work.

```
imap <C-space> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
nmap <C-space> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
vmap <C-space> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

Comment: The only solution that I encountered that worked for me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the sollution here: [How to debug vim mapping overlaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546495/how-to-debug-vim-mapping-overlaps)

You should use

```
nnoremap <SID>I_won’t_ever_type_this <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

So the imaps.vim of vim-latex don't remap . You can still have the functionality by mapping to something better.