# How to debug vim mapping overlaps?

Tags: vim, latex, mapping

In general how to debug and solve key bindings overlapping?
I had this problem..
Recently I add [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) plugin to my vim dir.
After that I noticed that my ctrl-j bind is overlapped by vim-latex/plugin/imaps.vim and lost a lot of time until solved that.

By the way: there is a bug in imaps.vim i think, because there is written " map only if there is no mapping already" and my example shows opposite.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get fine-grained info from the `:map` command:

To show only mappings relevant to a particular key (in this case ctrl-J):

```
:map <c-j>
```

or, better, to show mappings for particular key as well as the script where the mapping was set:

```
:verbose map <c-j>
```

Comment: Especially that with 'verbose' is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It is the addition to other people’s answers, not the answer itself.

> By the way: there is a bug in imaps.vim i think, because there is written " map only if there is no mapping already" and my example shows opposite.

You are mistaking what «mapping» here means. If you take a look at the code of `imaps.vim` you’ll see that it won’t create a mapping if there is a mapping to `<Plug>IMAP_JumpForward` ({rhs}), not if there is a `<C-j>` mapping ({lhs}). Thus you should use

```
nnoremap <SID>I_won’t_ever_type_this <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

in order to disable `<C-j>` remapping if you don’t need it (of course you could replace `<SID>...` part with something more meaningful if you do want to use this functionality).

Answer (score 1):

```
:map
```

Shows a list of your current maps.