# Mapping <C-j> in Vim for non-tex files, with Latex-Suite installed

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite

I've found some older posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304421/trouble-mapping-c-j-in-vim-with-latex-suite?noredirect=1&lq=1) that discuss the difficulty with mapping the `<C-j>` shortcut in vim, i.e.

```
map <C-j> <C-w>j
```

due to latex-suite's usage of `<C-j>` to jump forward in the text. I'm in a similar situation, but I would like to keep latex-suite's normal shortcuts for when editing tex files, and only use the new mapping when editing non-tex files. I'm a little confused by why this isn't the default behavior - latex-suite's `<C-j>` shortcut shows up as a shortcut in the `:map` output even when I don't have a tex file loaded and other shortcuts (like `` `a `` mapping to `\alpha`) don't work. Am I understanding correctly that unlike most of latex-suite's shortcuts, this `<C-j>` shortcut from latex-suite gets loaded regardless of filetype for some reason? And if so, how do I make it so that it only gets loaded for tex files, so that I can use other `<C-j>` mappings for non-tex files?

Answer (score 1):

The only sane solution would be for the maintainers of that plugin to move all their filetype-specific mappings to an ftplugin, where they belong. The way they currently implement them is a silly mix of good practices (`<Plug>`) and bad practices (global filetype-specific mappings), all in a single script under `plugin/`. This is very bad.

What they currently do:

```
" in plugin/imaps.vim

inoremap <silent> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward    <C-\><C-N>:call IMAP_Jumpfunc('', 0)<CR>

if !hasmapto('<Plug>IMAP_JumpForward', 'i')
    imap <C-J> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
endif
```

- The first mapping is okay-ish: plugin authors should use virtual `:help <Plug>` mappings as much as possible in order to allow users to write their own mappings easily. `IMAP_JumpForward` should be in parentheses, though.
- The `:help hasmapto()` guard is pointless.
- `plugin/imaps.vim` is a "global plugin". As such, whatever it does that is not explicitly scoped to a buffer or a window is done for every buffer and window. That `<C-j>` mapping only makes sense…

  - in the context of `tex` files, when using that latex-suite plugin,
  - if you actually use that `imaps.vim` plugin elsewhere.

What they should do:

```
" in plugin/imaps.vim

inoremap <silent> <Plug>(IMAP_JumpForward)    <C-\><C-N>:call IMAP_Jumpfunc('', 0)<CR>

" in ftplugin/**/<somefile>.vim

imap <buffer> <C-J> <Plug>(IMAP_JumpForward)
```

Frankly, the way that thing is designed should raise all kinds of red flags. I don't do (la)tex at all but https://github.com/lervag/vimtex seems more competently done.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment. I've strongly considered vimtex in the past and would love to switch to it - the only problem is that I've been using latex-suite for almost five years now, and I know all the shortcuts like the back of my hand. If there was an easy way to get vimtex up and running in a way that was as close as possible to latex-suite, I'd make the switch in a heartbeat.