# How to see the entire hint information when using hie (haskell ide engine) in vim 8?

Tags: haskell, vim

I'm familiarizing myself with hie on vim8.0.
The suggestion information below the status line would be pretty useful.
[image]
For example, in this case, the information is:

"... do filter gamelength  allWords :: IO WordList why not : filter gameLength..."

However I can only see part of the information. After googling for about 2 hours. I start to realize this information might be different from things in status-line.
I configured the hie following this instruction on my Mac.
https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine#using-hie-with-vim-or-neovim

So, my question is how can I see the entire information?

Thanks a lot for any possible help !

Comment: I can't be sure because I have never used HIE with Vim, but I suspect you can see the full message by opening [Vim's quickfix window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747091/2751851).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !  This is exactly what I want !!!

Comment: You're welcome. I have converted my comment into an answer, for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HIE is using Vim's quickfix window to display that linter message. You can expand the window with the `:copen` command. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747091/2751851) for other relevant commands.