# Using the quickfix window with vim+jslint

Tags: vim, jslint, quickfix

I'm using the vim+jslint combo described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/496086#496086), and am having problems figuring out how to use the two together. I'm guessing that the list of errors is supposed to show on the top half and the second half has the actual page? If so, how do I go about doing this? (Caution, I am completely new to the quickfix window, and the documentation isn't exactly the best at describing how to use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_30.html#30.1) documentation in the [user manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_toc.html#usr_toc.txt) section of Vim's help is good.  You have to remember, that Vim's help has both a user manual and a reference manual.  The latter is more terse.

The general run down is, after running `:make` the quickfix list is populated with anything the `'errorformat'` option has been configured to parse.  You use the `:cn` and `:cN` commands to move forward/backward through the quickfix list, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the user manual tip, I'll be looking for those more often now.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I hacked the jslint script to output in the format for the quickfix window. I replaced:

```
//print((e.evidence||'').replace(/^\s*(\S*(\s+\S+)*)\s*$/,"$1"));print('');
```

with

```
print(a[0]+':'+e.line+':'+e.reason)
```

I think