# Useful Vim plugins for web development and design (php, html, css, javascript)?

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins

Right now I'm using `surround.vim` to enclose text in HTML tags, and a [plugin](http://lanpartei.de/~niklas/vim/after/syntax/css-color-vim.png) that highlights text according to the hex value in the CSS file (e.g. #888 will have gray background in the CSS file).

Are there other useful plugins for web development?

**Recommendations**

Here is a list of the plugins mentioned in the answers so far:

- [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) to enclose text in HTML tags
- [jslint.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2729) to check for JavaScript errors with JSLint
- [Emmet.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) for HTML and CSS high-speed coding
- [phpfolding.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623) to for automatic folding of PHP
- [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) for automatic syntax checking of e.g. PHP
- [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) for tagging of a wide array of languages.
- [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) Helps view/navigate source, displays call signature in status area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600) explaining how to get JavaScript **syntax checking / linting** and **source-code browsing / tag-list** for Vim using the community-driven [jshint.com](http://jshint.com) (which is way better than JSLint IMO) and Mozilla's *DoctorJS* (formerly *jsctags*).

Answer (score 6):

I find [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) to be fairly helpful in spotting minor PHP problems. (and/or blend it with some form of setting php -l as :make.) Syntastic also shows you tidy warnings on your html.

Comment: +1 for syntastic, and it also works for javascript :)

Comment: You can also try ale plugin (w0rp/ale) it gets advantage of the new asynchronous functions

Answer (score 4):

How about JSLint right in VIM, http://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim ?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the plugins I'm currently using as well as some vimrc mappings to make things a bit easier.

**Plugins**

**[Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)** is an essential vim plugin for every user. It helps keep all the plugins you need organized within their own directories. This makes it much easier to uninstall plugins at a later time, since your plugins don't all live in the same tree. Pathogen will handle adding everything together at runtime.

**[Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)** adds the popular textmate feature that makes it easy to open files.

**[Snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim)** gives vim the power of textmate like snippets.

**[Sparkup](https://github.com/kogakure/vim-sparkup)** adds zencoding to vim to make it faster and easier to write HTML.

**[NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter)** makes it easy to toggle commented blocks of code.

**[Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)** adds syntax checking to lots of different file types, and if vim has signs support enabled, you get markers to the left of your line numbers telling you where your errors are.

**.vimrc config settings**

Encode/Decode HTML to HTML Entities (Great for writing documentation)

```
"EASILY ESCAPE OR UNESCAPE HTML
function HtmlEscape()
  silent s/&/\&amp;/eg
  silent s/</\&lt;/eg
  silent s/>/\&gt;/eg
endfunction

function HtmlUnEscape()
  silent s/&lt;/</eg
  silent s/&gt;/>/eg
  silent s/&amp;/\&/eg
endfunction

map <silent> <c-h> :call HtmlEscape()<CR>
map <silent> <c-u> :call HtmlUnEscape()<CR>
```

Toggle Relative Line Numbers (new VIM 7.3 feature)

```
function! g:ToggleNuMode() 
  if(&rnu == 1) 
    set nu 
  else 
    set rnu 
  endif 
endfunc
nnoremap <C-L> :call g:ToggleNuMode()<cr>
```

Highlight unwanted whitespace

```
"HIGHLIGHT POTENTIALLY UNWANTED WHITESPACE
highlight BadWhitespace term=standout ctermbg=red guibg=red
match BadWhitespace /[^* \t]\zs\s\+$\| \+\ze\t/
```

Answer (score 3):

I like ZenCoding : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981

Also, for folding Php : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623

Answer (score 3):

ctags aka [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)

[A blog post about it.](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19329)

That blog post also mentions the [taglist plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=273), which I have yet to use.

Comment: is taglist useful listing HTML and CSS elements?

Comment: @janoChen I haven't used taglist, though it seemed useful, so I included that in my answer.  That said, taglist simply displays information gathered by ctags.  According to the ctags website, it supports HTML, but there is no mention of CSS: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html  Personally, I used ctags on a large PHP codebase and found it very useful.

Answer (score 3):

[NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), [minibufexpl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159)

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful when dealing with html or xml: [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697); it allows to easily add/delete/change any kind of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted by someone else from [a couple of functions of mine](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/vbvzy/the_vim_holy_grail_why_the_hell_is_the_esc_key_so/c53iq0i) (in turn adapted [from others](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/HTML_entities)), [this plugin](https://github.com/pydave/textconv.vim) allows you to turn "special" characters into HTML entities (and back) or URL Escapes (and back).

This is *extremely* useful when writing stupid HTML Emails.