# Vim plugins, tips and tricks for Drupal development

Tags: drupal, vim

I am looking for usefull scripts, vim configurations and addons for Drupal development with Vim.

I am especially interested in experiences with various scripts, personal favorites and so on.

- [Drupal-vim vimrc](https://github.com/mengxy/drupal-vim)
- [Configuring vim on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/29325)

From [Useful Vim plugins for web development and design (php, html, css, javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173963/useful-vim-plugins-for-web-development-and-design-php-html-css-javascript)

- [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) to enclose text in HTML tags
- [jslint.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2729) to check for JavaScript errors and bad practices with JSLint
- [jshint.vim](https://github.com/wookiehangover/jshint.vim) to check for JavaScript errors and bad practices with JSHint (less brutal than JSLint)
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623 to for automatic folding of PHP
- [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) for automatic syntax checking of e.g. PHP
- [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) for tagging of a wide array of languages.
- Taglist Helps view/navigate source, displays call signature in status area.
- [Snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) snipmate with [Drupal texmate bundle](http://groups.drupal.org/node/6601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T-Command kicks ass and is not only for Drupal development. You will love it. See the video.

https://wincent.com/products/command-t

Comment: I think [ctrl-p](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) plugin is like this but adds functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to my .vimrc file. [at gist](https://gist.github.com/903741)
Specific to Drupal it:

- contains a hot key ([ctrl]+[n]) for "drush cc all".
- Associates .install .module and .inc files with php syntax highlighting.
- Checks php syntax before saving a file.