# vim javascript omnicomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, vim

I'm trying to get vim to provide some form of jQuery Omnicomplete. I have used ctags to generate tags based ont he jquery js file. After which I have turned on omnicompletion for javascript using

```
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
```

after which I set the tags variable to the tag file I created

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/jquery
```

When I open a js file, and use `:ta` I'm able to find the function I want, but when I try to use omnicompletion, it just doesn't turn up. For example, I took this code from the net to test:

```
$("input").has(".email").addClass("email_icon");
```

In VIM, after typing `$("input").`, I hit tab(with supertab set up) and `has` does not turn up, even though I can find it through fuzzy finder or `:ta`

Any suggestions as to what I can do to resolve this? Thanks!:)

Answer (score 7):

Use Mozilla's *DoctorJS* (formerly *jsctags*), which is also used in [Cloud9 IDE](http://www.cloud9ide.com/)'s [Ace online editor](http://ace.ajax.org/).

See my answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/5893600#5893600) for more info (install, config, etc.).

Comment: Can DoctorJS handle the jQuery source (the "Try It" feature doesn't seem to be able to).

Comment: I have no idea. Sorry. You'll have to try and see.

Comment: It seems to generate ctags for jquery plugins just fine, but not for jquery itself (it apparently used to long ago, but that's broken).

Answer (score 5):

`javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS` does not use the `ctags` file for completion.

What you can do is, you can write your own omni-complete function for jQuery, or even better, expand the `javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS` function defined in `/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/javascriptcomplete.vim` to suit your needs.

Comment: By the way, you can access tag-based completion with `C-x C-]`, or have SuperTab try it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get javascript autocompletion would be to use mozilla's 'jsctags' project. It generates better tags for javascript than 'exuberant ctags'. Hopefully you'll see more when you use supertab & taglist-plus.

For more info: http://www.discontinuously.com/2011/03/vim-support-javascript-taglist-plus/