# Code Validation Tools for Scripting Languages

Tags: validation, vim, scripting-language

I spent some two hours trying to understand why the JavaScript file I am including in my Facebook application is not showing when I view the source of my page. Then guess what the problem turned out to be? I forget to add the final closing bracket of a statement, and as Facebook processes the scripts before adding them (to avoid having unexpected errors in Facebook platform), it didn't attach this script because it has a syntax error!! That is, a whole JavaScript was not added because of a missing bracket!

So to save my time in the future I want to get some syntax validation tools for the scripting languages I am using: PHP, Python, JavaScript, MySQL (although not really a scripting language). Can anybody help me with that? It would be great if they are Vim plugins as I use it heavily.

Feel free to share validation tools for other programming languages, I don't want to keep this post for me only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tagged with `VIM` so I would suggeest to look at [jslint.vim](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim).

I use it (with a few fixes for Windows XP) with VIM 7.3.

Other nice (and much easier to setup on Windows) tool is [syntastic.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736). According to documentation it works for `eruby`, `haml`, `html`, `javascript`, `php`, `python`, `ruby` and `sass`.

Comment: Yes, vim is the most important tag here because I use it a lot :-) Thanks man!

Comment: Oh, syntastic.vim seems great. I will try it.

Comment: unfortunately, this plugin didn't work for me :-( Have you tried it? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Promather -- which one and on which operating system?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have updated you. I tried it again and it worked. I was talking about syntastic.vim. But I ended up removing it finally. It caused some conflicts with the find/replace I use, probably because I use lvimgrep rather than vimgrep. I should spend some time to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript: [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Python: [PyLint](http://www.logilab.org/857), [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/), [PyFlakes](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pyflakes/)

PHP: [Is there a static code analyzer [like Lint] for PHP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

With scrip^H^H^H^Hdynamic languages, i advise to carefully configure the various lint-like tools, because the style of programming and requirements of the project dictate different needs as for what should be forbidden or not.

For instance, you might want to avoid 'import *' in Python, except in a few cases. Or eval() except you *really* know what you are doing, etc.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint) VIM [plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441) to [integrate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=891) these tools.

Comment: For other languages, search ie. "Ruby lint". It's also useful to read the rationale behind the style guides. You might find that Google has different needs than you: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html. The same goes for PEP8 or Crockford's advices.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JS Editor available from http://www.yaldex.com/Free_JavaScript_Editor.htm

Their interface is really nice but restricted to Javascript only.

I have used Notepad++ in the past which highlights syntax sufficiently well but lacks other features you'd normally expect in an IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works under Windows and I am a Linux programmer.