# How to configure Syntastic with JSHint?

Tags: vim, jshint, syntastic

How to use the Syntastic Vim plugin with JSHint to validate JavaScript code?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 11.04
- VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

What I have installed, following the solution at [VIM + JSLint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447):

- [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)
- node.js
- Node Package Manager
- jshint, globally
- Syntastic installed through Vundle (Used the :BundleInstall command inside Vim to make sure Syntastic was installed.)

.vimrc:

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'

filetype plugin indent on     " required! 

let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_jump=1
let g:syntastic_stl_format = '[%E{Err: %fe #%e}%B{, }%W{Warn: %fw #%w}]'

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
```

looking for installed executables:

```
$ which gjslint
$ which jslint
$ which jsl
$ which jshint
/home/fernando/local/node/bin/jshint
$ 


$ echo $PATH

>/home/fernando/local/bin:/home/fernando/local/node/bin:/home/fernando/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

$ jshint test.js
```

> test.js: line 3, col 1, 'blbla' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 4, col 1, 'x' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 4, col 5, 'nonono' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 6, col 1, 'a' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 7, col 1, 'b' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 8, col 5, 'a' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 8, col 10, 'b' is not defined.
>   test.js: line 8, col 7, Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> 8 errors

```
$ vi test.js -- no error message shown

:SyntasticEnable -- Vim exits and restarts, opening the same file, but still no message

:w -- still no error message

:Errors -- the location list opens but it is empty
```

Both jshint and Syntastic seem to be installed, but something is probably missing. What would it be?

Comment: Very weird! I just tried Syntastic with Vim 7.3 on Linux without any trouble. Maybe file an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is a more updated info, there is a configuration to associate a file extension to a checker,
in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
```

Also to get info about what's going on run this command in vim

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

And you'll get an output similar to this:

```
Syntastic info for filetype: javascript  
Available checkers: gjslint jshint  
Currently active checker(s): gjslint  
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Don't you mean `jshint` instead of `jslint`, as par the question?

Comment: OP here; I confirm that this works: `let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']`.

Comment: Just to note, in 2018... jshint seems to be out of the box the defacto for Syntastic. I never did the first part of this but in 2018 vim after running the info command I see `Available checker: jshint. Currently enabled checker: jshint`

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same problem. Turns out, Syntastic looks for `jsl` (JSLint) before it looks for jshint. If you have both installed, you'll likely be misled. I moved `jsl` somewhere not in my PATH, and jshint was detected just fine.

Source:
https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/pull/47

Comment: That's useful advice, but in my case I don't think I had jsl on the path, since I used the "which jsl" command to look for it.

Comment: I have "jslint" and "jshint" on my PATH. For some reason Syntastic did not show feedback for jslint. Removing jslint from PATH let Syntastic use jshint instead, which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for days and `SyntasticInfo` would not recognize `jshint` as an available checker even after i added `let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers['jshint']` to my `.vimrc`.  I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519189/how-can-i-get-jshint-to-work) tutorial to install nvm, nodejs, and jshint on Ubuntu.  After I did that I discovered that if I removed the line `filetype plugin indent on` from my `.vimrc` then opened a `.js` file everything worked perfectly!  To summarize...

1. follow the tutorial linked above
2. add `~/.nvm/<version_number>/bin` to path in `.bashrc`
3. remove `filetype plugin indent on` from `.vimrc`
4. add `let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers['jshint']` to `.vimrc`
5. `:so %` inside vim
6. open a `.js` file
7. add `filetype plugin indent on` back to your `.vimrc`
8. everything magically works now