# Syntastic doesn't detect JSHint as an available checker

Tags: vim, jshint, syntastic

I have installed Syntastic with Pathogen.

Syntastic works for Python files but not for JavaScript files with JSHint.
JSHint works via command line or with other vim plugin like https://github.com/Shutnik/jshint2.vim

```
→ which jshint  
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/jshint

→ jshint --version
jshint v2.1.10

→ echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I run :SyntasticInfo, it doesn't find any checkers.

```
Syntastic info for filetype: javascript
Available checkers:
Currently active checker(s):
```

My vimrc

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
```

I don't know what I've missed, if you have any idea why Syntastic doesn't detect JSHint. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching for "syntastic" and "jshint"? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7233005

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Syntastic with JSHint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233005/how-to-configure-syntastic-with-jshint)

Comment: Yes I already tried and saw this post, but it does not work for me. I just wonder why JSHint is not an available chercker.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Long story short; Syntastic needs the path of jshint.

---

I encountered a similar problem on Windows 8. After installing `nodejs` v0.10.22 and `syntastic` >= 3.2.0, the Vim command `:SyntasticInfo` would give me:

```
Syntastic: active mode enabled
Syntastic info for filetype: vim
Available checker(s): 
Currently enabled checker(s):
```

The documentation over at [jshint.com/docs](http://jshint.com/docs/) suggests that this is sufficient to install the module.

```
$ npm install jshint -g
```

This is true, apart from a somewhat surprising meaning of ***flag -g installs JSHint globally on your system***.  It means in your user's %AppData% folder:

```
(abbreviated output from previous command)
C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\npm\jshint -> \
C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint\bin\jshint
jshint@2.3.0 C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint
├── console-browserify@0.1.6
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
└── cli@0.4.5 (glob@3.2.7)
```

Another piece of documentation from the [syntastic FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) reads:

> Q. I installed syntastic but it isn't reporting any errors...
>
> A. ***The most likely reason is that none of the syntax checkers that it requires is installed.*** For example: python requires either flake8, pyflakes or pylint to be installed and in $PATH. To see which executables are supported, just look in syntax_checkers//*.vim. ***Note that aliases do not work; the actual executable must be available in your $PATH.*** Symbolic links are okay. You can see syntastic's idea of available checkers by running :SyntasticInfo.

The solution amounts to setting the path of the `jshint` command in ~/.vimrc:

```
 let g:syntastic_jshint_exec='C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\npm\jshint.cmd'

:source $HOME/_vimrc
:SyntasticInfo
Syntastic: active mode enabled
Syntastic info for filetype: javascript
Available checker(s): jshint
Currently enabled checker(s): jshint
```

Alternatively, one could:

```
> cmd.exe
> cd C:\Users\jaroslav\AppData\Roaming\npm
> setx PATH "%cd%:%PATH%"
```

and `let g:syntastic_jshint_exec='jshint.cmd'`. I didn't try the last solution with %PATH% because Winders doesn't like long %PATH% variables.

### Hopefully this saves you some time.

Comment: Also beware that syntastic requires jshint >= 1.0, it won’t register versions below that.