# Syntastic with jslint for vim not executing the checker

Tags: javascript, vim, jslint, vim-plugin

I have set up `Syntastic` https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic with vim and I would like to use it for node.js javascript linting.

I have installed `jslint`

```
$ jslint routes/index.js

routes/index.js
 #1 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    module.exports = function(app) { // Line 5, Pos 26
    ....
```

And I have put this in my `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_jslint_checkers=['jslint']
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
```

But I get no output on `:SyntasticCheck`

Yet

```
Syntastic: active mode enabled
Syntastic info for filetype: javascript
Available checker(s): jslint
Currently enabled checker(s): jslint
```

Comment: What does `:Errors` produce on a JavaScript file?

Comment: @mareser No output at all - the same as with `:SyntasticCheck`. Yet I can use `jslint` in commandline.

Comment: If you are not forced to use jslint I'd recommend jshint. Instructions found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447).

Comment: It works with `jshint` ;) you can post an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend **JSHint** as an alternative for JavaScript linting in Vim. Here is a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint/5893447#5893447) that explains how to install it.

If you want to use JSHint for creating web sites as well, I'd additionally use [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/). This way your JavaScript and your HTML code stay separated (JSHint can't deal with JavaScript inside HTML files).