# configure js linter to warn on missing variable definition

Tags: javascript, vim, jslint, jshint

Suppose I'm working with the javascript below:

```
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 6
};
new google.maps.Map('#map', mapOption);
```

I've mistakenly passed `mapOption` instead of `mapOptions`.  Is there a javascript linter that will pick up on this mistake?  Either warning me that `mapOption` is undefined or that `mapOptions` is unused?

I would love to have this functionality with jshint and vim, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Syntastic (https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) allows you to use jshint to lint javascript.  List of supported linters: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Syntax-Checkers

Comment: `mapOption` could be defined in another file or at runtime so there is no error here. You can use jhint's `unused` option, though. You should look into code coverage tools instead like Istanbul or Blanket.

Comment: @EvergreenTree I have seen syntastic /jshint check for missing semicolons but not the error above.

Comment: @romainl ah, thanks for those tips!

Comment: You've lost me; that's exactly what JSLint does. JSLint would complain that, **"'mapOption' was used before it was defined."** if you linted that code, along with a complaint about using `google` without defining it, if you don't have a `global` directive, and that you're using `new` for side effects. **I think your question is, "How do I set up a linter with VIm?"**, and that's got [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473478/vim-jslint). Sound right? ;^)